# Order by id in one column and then by id in another column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Table structure:

```
CategoryID   Name               ParentCategoryID

1            Parent             0
2            in parent1         1
3            in parent2         1
4            under in parent1   2
5            under in parent2   3
```

I want to return to the view a list storted by first the parent category, and then the category under each parent.

Eg. I want this sort in my view:

```
Parent
in parent1
under in parent1
in parent1
under in parent2
```

I have tested with `OderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
all = db.FileUploadCategories.OrderBy(c => c.CategoryID).ThenBy(p => p.ParentCategoryID).ToList();
```

But I get a list only sorted by CategoryID. Guess I should use `GroupBy` but but it does not work either. Get error in ParentID

```
all = db.FileUploadCategories.GroupBy(c => c.CategoryID).OrderBy(p => p.ParentCategoryID).ToList();
```

Comment: db.FileUploadCategories.OrderBy(x => x...).ThenBy(y => y...)

Comment: with OrderBy(...).OrderBy(...) you "destory" the first OrderBy

Comment: I have OrderBy and ThenBy but get a list sorted only by CategoryID. Same with OrderBy(p => p.ParentCategoryID).ThenBy(c => c.CategoryID)

Comment: As your CategoryID's are unique, the ThenBy has no effect. Try to OrderBy the Name and not the CategoryId.

Comment: `db.FileUploadCategories.OrderBy(n => n.CategoryName).ThenBy(a => a.ParentCategoryID).ToList(); ` gives me a strange sorting

Comment: what do you mean strange ?

Comment: as your question, you need the result as, first the parent category, and then the category under each parent, so first order by parent and then by child. ex: OrderBy(w=>w.ParentCategoryId).ThenBy(w=>w.CategoryName)